ошибка удаления записи sqlite
есть в бд две таблицы user и rang(есть внешний ключ на таблицу user). понадобилось удалить все записи из обоих таблиц. при вводе команды delete from user where id>0; получаю ошибку
при попытке ввода такой же команды, но для таблицы rang, вылезает та же самая ошибка.
так понимаю проблема во внешнем ключе, который связывает поля таблицы? и как теперь удалять записи?

настроить каскадное удаление... https://metanit.com/sql/sqlite/2.4.php

а это можно сделать в существующей таблице или такой параметр можно указать только при создании?

По идее да, https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

при попытке ввода такой же команды, но для таблицы rang, вылезает та же самая ошибка - Не верю! (с) Покажите DDL создания таблиц.

В sqlite можно отключить проверку внешних ключей: Enabling Foreign Key Support. Но это грязный хак.
